# Is there something better than useContext for passing general props?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js, tsx

I'm trying to re build an app that I started working with React, but now using Next JS. The way I passed props between components was by prop drilling in react. Now, with Next JS app directory I'm able to create a general layout for the page. The problem here is that what i want as general layout, a header and a left sidebar, need to be able to create elements in a main component, which is nested inside the layout.
To make what I'm trying to do in Next I need to pass props from the left sidebar to the main container. According to the Next JS 13 documentation, it is not possible to pass props from the layout to children components. I read and made a little investigation, and I came to the conclusion that using contexts would be the best approach, but I'm new with this, so is this the best way to go?

Extras (in case you need to know):
-Language: Typescript (TS, TSX)